# array size n into k same size groups

Tags: arrays, algorithm, computer-science, median-of-medians

I have an *unsorted* array of size *n* and I need to find *k-1* divisors so every subset is of the same size (like after the array is sorted).

I have seen this question with *k-1=3*. I  guess I need the median of medians and this is will take *o(n)*. But I think we should do it *k* times so *o(nk)*.
I would like to understand why it would take *o(n logk)*.

For example: I have an unsorted array with integers and I want find the *k*'th divisors which is the k-1 integers that split the array into k (same sized) subarrays according to their values.
If I have `[1, 13, 6, 7, 81, 9, 10, 11]` the 3=k dividers is `[7 ,11]` spliting to `[1 6, 9 10 13 81]` where every subset is big as 2 and equal.

Comment: can you give an example testcase?

Comment: @A.Shoob  Good on you.  Now, please delete your comments that say the same thing.  This will help to reduce the number of total comments.  (I'll be deleting mine too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a divide-and-conquer approach.  First, find the `(k-1)/2`th divider using the median-of-medians algorithm.  Next, use the selected element to partition the list into two sub-lists.  Repeat the algorithm on each sub-list to find the remaining dividers.

The maximum recursion depth is `O(log k)` and the total cost across all sub-lists at each level is `O(n)`, so this is an `O(n log k)` algorithm.